# Creating and Discarding JFrames that run Threads

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-threads

I'm writing my Tetris using Java Swing. The Game class revolves around a JFrame (frame), which consists of a TetrisPanel extending JPanel (panel) where the blocks fall, a JLabel (pontok) point counter, a JTextArea (rekord_text) showing high scores, and another JPanel (kovi) showing the next block to fall. My idea is that the game has 3 difficulty levels, where the blocks fall with different speed.

I thought the best way of approaching this problem is to create a new JFrame with the components above, but with the blocks' speed set different. I am able to close the old JFrame. However, when the new JFrame opens up, it is only a blank frame, and it won't respond to closing the window.

I should add that TetrisPanel is running a thread, but I am 90% sure I stop that with a volatile boolean.

Constructor of the Game class:

```
        this.difSet(nehezseg);  //this function sets the falling velocity
        TetrisPanel.stopped = true;  //this static member is the volatile boolean responsible for stopping the thread
        new_game = false;

        frame = new JFrame("Tetris_alpha");

        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        panel = new TetrisPanel();
        TetrisPanel.stopped = false;
        new Thread(panel).start();
        frame.add(panel, c);

        pontok = new JLabel ("0");
        frame.add(pontok, c);

        rekord_text = new JTextArea();
        //i set up the area
        frame.add(rekord_text, c);

        kovi = new NextAktualPanel();
        frame.add(kovi, c);

        menu = new MyMenu(this);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                        rekordok.add(panel.getPont());
                        rekordok.write(f);
                        e.getWindow().dispose();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
        );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The Game.start() function containing the game loop:

```
public void start()
    {
        //game_loop
        while (!panel.GameOver() && !new_game)
        {
                if (panel.aktualLeertDetector())
                {   
                    panel.addAktualToBlocks();
                    panel.addNewAktual(next);
                    Elem temp = new Elem(0,0,rand.nextInt(7)); 
                    while (temp.getTipus() == next.getTipus())
                        temp = new Elem(0,0,rand.nextInt(7));
                    next = temp;
                    kovi.setNextAktual (next);
                }
                if (!paused)
                    pontok.setText(Integer.toString(panel.getPont()));
                kovi.repaint();
                panel.repaint();
        }
```

The function which opens the new frame:

```
Public void newGame (Game g)
{
            Game.new_game = true;
            g.frame.dispose();
            Game new_game = new Game("easy");
            g = new_game;
            g.start();
}
```

And the run() function of TetrisPanel:

```
public static volatile boolean stopped = false;
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopped)
        {
            aktual.zuhan();
            this.sorTeleAction();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, including ideas about different a approach.

Comment: Swing shouldn't be used by threads other than the AWT Event Dispatch Thread. If you want a time delay, use `javax.swing.Timer` (careful not to use the other timer confusingly of the same name).

Comment: Your code looks to be flouting Swing threading rules. If you haven't yet read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), now is a good time as this link will explain those rules, how to follow them, and why they're important. Then yes, do what @TomHawtin suggests -- use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive your game loop.

Comment: Another relevant link: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: *I thought the best way of approaching this problem is to create a new JFrame with the components* - there is no need to create a new JFrame. You game logic just needs a "reset" method. When you use a JTextField you just use `setText(...)` to change the text. When you use a JTable you can just change the TableModel. In either case you don't create a new component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use volatile boolean as status variable, use AtomicBoolean instead, volatile it's not the correct way to do this kind of things, and it does not either cause "immediate variable updating"... this is not volatile purpose.
2. It's not a good idea to start a thread on main AWT thread, you still have to use *SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnableAction)*. You can use something like this when launching a Gui Thread:

   ```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       new Thread(threadAction).start();
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                   }
               }
         });
   ```

Hope that this will solve you problem!